# How do I install DHCP on a Windows 2012 Server core instance?

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2012

I attempt to run the Powershell command:

```
 Install-WindowsFeature DHCP
```

and get the message:

[image]

But if I attempt to create the static IP address, I get:
[image]

Which I think is the result of not having DHCP installed.

Comment: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) is probably a better place for this type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Server Core installations a DHCP address is provided by default.

If you need to edit it, use these steps:

At a command prompt, type the following:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces
```

Make a note of the number shown in the Idx column of the output for your network adapter. If your computer has more than one network adapter, make a note of the number corresponding to the network adapter for which you wish to set a static IP address.
At the command prompt, type:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="<ID>" source=static address=<StaticIP> mask=<SubnetMask> gateway=<DefaultGateway>
```

Where:
ID is the number from step 2 above.
StaticIP is the static IP address that you are setting.
SubnetMask is the subnet mask for the IP address.
DefaultGateway is the default gateway.
At the command prompt, type:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver name="<ID>" address=<DNSIP>index=1
```

Where:
ID is the number from step 2 above.
DNSIP is the IP address of your DNS server.